# How usual is it?

Tags: derivatives

I have this question in my question bank

**With usual notation ,$\frac{d^{2}x}{dy^{2}}$ is**
$$\begin{align}
&1)\left(\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}\right)^{-1}\\
&2)\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^{-2}\\
&3)-\left(\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}\right)^{-1}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^{-2}\\
&4)\left(\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}\right)\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^{-3}\\
\end{align}$$

I do not understand how to represent second order derivative in one of the given forms. 
This **HINT** is also provided with the question: $\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)=\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^{-1}$ now differentiate both side wrt $y$
if somehow it is correct to differentiate then I got stuck here 
$=-1\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^{-2}\cdot \frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$
applied chain rule. If I again use there inverse of derivative technique I'll get what I started with, I want to know is it a correct question? and are there such **usual notations**?,  thanks